# Sort everything except first element, qsort C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, qsort

I do have something odd. I would like to sort an array of many elements by colour on a chess board. This is quite easy (see attached code), so if x%2==y%2 is true, then it's black, if not it's white.
But that's not the problem. I do have one element at the front of the array, which is a little bit different (need that for some calculation later) and needs to stay where it is.

Is it possible to sort an array without touching the first element?

```
int compareColour(const void * fs1, const void * fs2) {
    Field *orderA = (Field *)fs1;
    Field *orderB = (Field *)fs2;

    bool isBlackB = ((orderA->x%2)==(orderA->y%2));
    bool isBlackA = ((orderB->x%2)==(orderB->y%2));
    return (isBlackB - isBlackA);
}

void sortByColour() {
    qsort(fieldArr,(size_t) countFields, sizeof(Field), compareColour);
}
```

Comment: `qsort(fieldArr+1, countFields-1`

Comment: As @user3386109 indicates, don't include the first element in the array being passed to the sort.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it's working this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just pass a pointer to the second element (i.e., the one at index 1) instead of the array's beginning and reduce the count by one, as @ user3386109 commented:

```
qsort(fieldArr + 1, (size_t) (countFields - 1), sizeof(Field), compareColour);
/* 2nd element---^ */
/* Reduce the count ----------------------^ */
```

Comment: That's in fact much easer than I have ever though. Thank you!

Comment: First you should check that the original array is not null has a length of at least 2.